# RocksDB JNI Slow Read Performance

Tags: database, performance, rocksdb-java

I am using RocksDB JNI and I found that reads are getting exponentially slow for this program

Initially, it's in an acceptable range. But when the program runs so that the total records reach 1 million then the read time logger prints are showing around 200-300 ms. Getting still worse, as the program runs. Am I using the JNI wrong?

```
long n = 0;
int counter = 0;
try(
final Options options = new Options()
.setCreateIfMissing(true)
.setComparator(new Comparator(new ComparatorOptions()){

                @Override
                public String name() {
                    return "default";
                }

                @Override
                public int compare(final Slice a, final Slice b) {
                    long x = ByteBuffer.wrap(a.data()).getLong();
                        long y = ByteBuffer.wrap(b.data()).getLong();
                        return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
                }
            })
                    .setWriteBufferSize(64 * SizeUnit.MB)
                    .setMaxWriteBufferNumber(6)
                    .setMinWriteBufferNumberToMerge(2);
            final RocksDB db = RocksDB.open(options, "/PathToDB/")){
        boolean loop = true;
        while(loop) {
            if(n == Long.MAX_VALUE){
                loop = false;
            }
            for (int j=0;j<4;j++){
                try(WriteBatch writeBatch = new WriteBatch()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                        String urlStr = "dummy"+counter;
                        counter++;
                        Long score = getScore(urlStr);
                        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
                        buf.putLong(score);
                        writeBatch.put( buf.array() , urlStr.getBytes(UTF_8));
                    }
                    long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    db.write(new WriteOptions(), writeBatch);
                    long et = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    logger.logMessage(Test.class.getName(), Level.INFO, "RocksDB write of 200 URLs successful. Time taken - {0}", new Object[]{ et-st});
                } catch (RocksDBException ex) {

                }
            }
            byte[] firstKey = null, lastKey = null;
            int readC = 0;
            long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final RocksIterator it = db.newIterator();
            it.seekToFirst();
            while(it.isValid() && readC < 50){
                lastKey = it.key();
                if(firstKey == null){
                    firstKey = lastKey;
                }
                it.next();
                readC++;
            }
            long et = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.logMessage(Test.class.getName(), Level.INFO, "RocksDB read of 50 URLs successful. Time taken - {0}", new Object[]{ et-st});
            if(lastKey != null){
                db.deleteRange(firstKey, lastKey);
            }
            n++;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.logMessage(Level.SEVERE, Test.class.getName(), e);
    }
```